# Typescript check the function input parameters if they contain same properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I need a function that takes two objects A and B and returns a string.

However, the properties of A and B should be all unique: no property should be
in both objects. And I want the compiler to typecheck that for me.

```js
myFunction({a:1}, {b:1, c:1}) // Should be OK
myFunction({a:1}, {a:1, b:1, c:1}) // Should NOT be OK, since both objects contain "a"
```

This is what I got so far, but I run into `Type parameter 'B' has a circular constraint.ts(2313)` error.

```js
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : U

function myFunction<A,  B extends Exclude<A,B>,>(a:A, b:B) : Exclude<A,B> {
  // do something with a and b here 
  return 's' as any // would be nice if I don't need to cast here
}

const x = myFunction({a:1}, {a:1}) // Should produce an typescript error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really understand why you're having trouble returning a string; surely you'd want the return type to be `string` and not `Exclude<A, B>`, right? Or, put another way, why would you expect that `Exclude<A, B>` would be stringlike at all?  Could you fix that up?  Anyway, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Na1bEN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer (once the `string` situation is resolved in the question); if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

so i got it working (partly):

```
type Exclude<A, U> = U extends A ? never : U;

function myFunction<
  T extends object,
  U extends Exclude<T, P>,
  P extends object = U
>(a: T, b: U) {
  return "something";
}

myFunction({ a: 1 }, { a: 1 }); // Error
myFunction({ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }); // OK
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-davinci-72nvqs?file=/src/index.ts